# Cygwin: struggling with bash commands not being found

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have installed `Cygwin DLL 2.10.0`, the latest version of Cygwin, from https://www.cygwin.com/. However, I am struggling to get some basic commands working like:

`cygcheck`, `mount`, and any other package in the Cygwin utilities listed in their documentation (https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html). I looked over their installation instructions and it seems like Cygwin should be straightforward: select packages for installation by checking some boxes then "next." I have set-up a working Cygwin installation on my work laptop but am struggling to do the same on my personal Windows 10 PC.

In Cygwin, I get an error like:

```
$ mount
-bash: mount: command not found
```

I read about the `which` command to help debug, but not quite sure how to decipher the output:

```
$ which cygcheck
which: no cygcheck in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/                                                      System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime                                                      /QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdr                                                      ive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Sk                                                      ype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin:                                                      /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Apple/Internet Services:/cygdrive/c                                                      /Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/U                                                      CRT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/UCRT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/I                                                      ntel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R                                                      ) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R                                                      ) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Mana                                                      gement Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/c                                                      ygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v                                                      1.0:/cygdrive/c/Users/alohakid/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/lib/l                                                      apack)
```

Any resources or troubleshooting tips are appreciated.

Perhaps related is that when I start Cygwin on my personal PC, I get the following errors:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/locale: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/tzset: No such file or directory
```

and my `backspace` button is interpreted as a `space` command. I do not observe any of this behavior on my work laptop's Cygwin installation. I am not running Mintty.

Comment: Can you add how you installed cygwin? I suspect you ticked/unticked some essential options during installation. If you have no cygcheck you won't be able to do much.

Comment: Are you running the login shell from Mintty (Cygwin Terminal) ?

Comment: @matzeri no, I am not

Comment: @HoD I downloaded the installer and clicked "Next" multiple times. I didn't tick/untick anything during the initial installation.

Comment: How are you running the bash ?